# Transferir um arquivo .bat para a pasta Startup do Windows estando dentro do Java

Tags: java

Bom dia galera, como diz o título, estou fazendo um projeto que contem um .bat e preciso transferir ele para a pasta startup do windows estando dentro do java (através de comandos), alguém sabe se isso é possível? Se sim, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Sim é possivel mover um arquivo usando. Veja se ajuda: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#renameTo(java.io.File)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // Caminho do arquivo .bat que você quer copiar
            Path sourceFile = Paths.get("seu_caminho_aqui");

            // Caminho da pasta de inicialização do Windows
            Path startupFolder = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"), "AppData", "Roaming", "Microsoft", "Windows", "Start Menu", "Programs", "Startup");

            // Caminho de destino para o arquivo .bat na pasta de inicialização
            Path targetFile = startupFolder.resolve(sourceFile.getFileName());

            // Copia o arquivo para a pasta de inicialização
            Files.copy(sourceFile, targetFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Links pertinentes:

- [Interface Path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html)
- [`Files.copy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-)